# Random Number Game

Tags: c++

I'm making a small game in C++ where a user will type "roll" and the program should generate 5 numbers between 1-6. The objective of the game is to get all the numbers the same.

My problem I am having is fully understanding how to format the different algorithms need for a project like this and what type of different syntax's that allowed through the language.

I am a student learning this language and will appreciate any help anyone is willing to offer!

The code below is not finished in anyway and just wanted some extra advice!

Code:

```
// Random Number Game 
// ***
// ***

#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{

    // Intro Instruction
    cout << "Welcome to Random Number game!\n";
    cout << "The objective of this game to get all 5 dice the same number.\n";

    // Variables
    char roll;
    int dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5;

    cout << "To begin the game please type roll. ";
    cin >> roll; 

    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    // Stating Low and High Numbers (Dice numbers)
    int lowerrange = 1;
    int upperrange = 7;

    upperrange = 6;

    dice1 = rand() % 6;
    dice2 = rand() % 6;
    dice3 = rand() % 6;
    dice4 = rand() % 6;
    dice5 = rand() % 6;

    if ((roll == 'roll') || (roll == 'Roll'))
    {
        cout << dice1; 
        cout << dice2;
        cout << dice3;
        cout << dice4;
        cout << dice5;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your actual question?  Is it not working?  Not compiling?  Post the relevant information as part of your question.

Comment: Looks like that should work, you could throw the whole thing in another loop so it can be "played" more than once.

Comment: Please don't tag C++ questions with the [tag:c] tag. I've fixed that for you.

Comment: One problem I notice right off the bat is your variable named "roll" is a char.  When you grab roll from cin, you are expecting a String (or char [] in C++ if I recall correctly :) ), not a character.  This will cause problems for you I believe.

Before this gets closed or put on hold for vagueness, the best way to learn is to do what you are doing - build fun programs, run into problems, and ask specific questions to figure out things you have no idea how to answer without help.  Eventually these things will come as second nature as you progress through the learning process.

Comment: @rost0031 Sorry, we edited the question at the same time, so your edit got rejected.

Comment: You set a low and high range, but use the magical number `6` for your dice rolls.  You should be using math here instead.  Also, this will give you numbers from 0 to 5.  Consider adding the `lowerrange` to the whole range for your rolls.  Your re-assignment of `upperrange `is probably wrong as well.

Comment: One last critique - if you have been taught how to use arrays, you should consider using them to store your dice rolls (along with a for loop.)   This will simplify the code in general.  You are also missing the step of checking for a yahtzee (all dice numbers the same).

Comment: I would check the user input *before* executing half the program

Comment: What wasn't working was the numbers would not show in the console and would not generate.

Comment: @Imcphers So instead of     char roll; I need to make char[roll] is what you are saying?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution.
The idea is to use a loop to repeatedly asking from user to "roll" the dices, for testing purposes only I put 3 dices here, but you can extend to 5 dices.

I maintain a `boolean` variable that will be true if and only if all the dices has the same value, if that the case, the program will break out from loop, and will print a successful message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   // Intro Instruction
   cout << "Welcome to Random Number game!\n";
   cout << "The objective of this game to get all 5 dice the same number.\n";

   string command;
   int magic = 0;

   do
   {
      cout << "To begin the game please type roll: ";
      cin >> command;

      if(command == "roll")
      {
         int dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
         int dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
         int dice3 = rand() % 6 + 1;

         cout << "First Dice: " << dice1 << endl;
         cout << "Second Dice: " << dice2 << endl;
         cout << "Third Dice: " << dice3 << endl;

         cout << "Which Dice do you want to keep? : (Enter 1, 2 or 3)" << endl;
         int keep_dice;
         cin >> keep_dice;

         if(keep_dice == 1)
         {
            magic = dice1;
            break;
         }
         else if(keep_dice == 2)
         {
            magic = dice2;
            break;
         }
         else if(keep_dice == 3)
         {
            magic = dice3;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   while(true);

   cout << "You choose the number: " << magic << ". Roll the other dices until you get for both this number." << endl;    

   do
   {
      cout << "Type roll: ";
      cin >> command;

      if(command == "roll")
      {
         int dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
         int dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;

         cout << "First Dice: " << dice1 << endl;
         cout << "Second Dice: " << dice2 << endl;

         if(dice1 == magic && dice2 == magic)
         { 
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   while(true);


   cout << "You won !" << endl;

}
```

**Alternative Solution:**
My idea is to create a function that will accept two parameters: `num_dice` the remaining dices to be rolled if you have 5 dices that will be 4, if you have `n` dices this will be `n-1` and so on.

The other parameter will be the `lucky number` that the user will choose (easy with an `if` or with [`switch`](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html) statement)

You will then repeat that with the same logic within your function until you get your `n-1 dices` equal to `lucky number`.

Moreover, think that my code may need a bit alteration, so that the first roll of **all** dices will happen once and not repeatedly, and then with the function you will do the repeat "job".

Comment: So I ran the code and it works, but how would you make it so the user can choose which dice to keep and roll the ones he doesn't then ?      This is set up way better than I had it so thank you!

Comment: Hey I didn't consider that in my implementation, I didn't understand basically, give me a second and I will come back to you.

Comment: Well done making it only work with 3 dice of a fixed range so that OP has some extra work to do.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan sorry I did something wrong? What do you mean by OP ?

Comment: No no, you did well.  I'm sorry if that came across as sarcastic.  I'd rather not give entire homework solutions away and teach nothing.  What you have here is a good basis to work from without doing the whole thing for him.  The missing dice to select part will actually be a bit harder to do, which is good as well.

Comment: Yes sure, thanks. @MakStahl I will edit my solution with some hints if you wish.

Comment: What he showed up in the code actually just showed me a lot about how to format the code and actually gone through the process @PyPiper in the small time taught me a lot! I didn't know that you can have more than one line in an if statement b/c the book that is provided for me only has one line not multiple like he has it. By showing me this, I now know I can do that, thank you .

Comment: Exactly, but because you still have to do some additional work, you cannot just gobble this up as-is and turn it in for credit, learning nothing.  I've seen a lot of "give me the cod3z!" posts and hate having them answered.  You have shown some effort in understanding, but still have some work to do to finish your assignment.

Comment: I agree with Michael Dorgan, also thank you Mak and I am happy that I helped. Please see my hint in my edited answer and do your best to come to the solution, you will feel better implementing the code, rather than copy pasting it.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan total get where you are going and agree with you, all the help is appreciated. I do want to learn this language so I can one day provide help for others and even make cool programs! I don't like laziness like that "just give me the code" helpful additions are great learned a lot from just the few posts :)

Comment: @PyPiper with choosing a lucky number simply adding another variable and stating that.. if number is chosen then all dice not that number re-roll. Am I hitting that concept pretty well for what you are describing? If so I'lll get right on that and show you guys when I am done :)

Comment: As an aside, I would not use `a == b == c` in production code.  I would use  `a == b && a == c' - slightly longer, but it makes be feel more comfortable :)

Comment: @MakStahl Well, is not what I was trying to describe but if you think this will work, try it out. What I was saying, is that, having a general function that will accept two parameters (`number_of_dices_to_be_rolled` and `win_number`) this function will roll only the `number_of_dices_to_be_rolled` (i.e in the above example with 3 dices this variable will be = `2`) until both of them hit the number->`win_number`. 
Michael Dorgan you are right, but this way is more clear and minimal so that the OP can see what happening there.

Comment: Ok thanks @PyPiper and MichaelDorgan I am going to read up on functions and get back to you guys in a little bit about this. Thank you very much for the info so far!

Comment: @MakStahl please see my edited answer and let me know if that is what you need. As a motivation, I will also encourage you to try implement that with function !

Answer (score 0):

To check if all the dices are the same, use the code below:

```
int magicValue = dice1;

cout << "You got:" << endl;
cout << "Dice 1: " << dice1 << endl;
cout << "Dice 2: " << dice2 << endl;
cout << "Dice 3: " << dice3 << endl;
cout << "Dice 4: " << dice4 << endl;
cout << "Dice 5: " << dice5 << endl;

if(dice2 == magicValue && dice3 == magicValue
   && dice4 == magicValue && dice5 == magicValue){
    cout << "Congratulations! You Win!" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Sorry, try again next time!" << endl;
}
```

What this does is it sets magicValue to dice1 and checks if all other dice variables are equal. Not the fanciest way to do it, but I hope this helps you!

Comment: By using this code will I need to add anything to make it so the user can choose which dice he/she keeps?

Comment: So when I added the code and changed the || to && when I compiled and ran it no numbers generated and just says "Sorry, try again next time!" Is there a problem with how I wrote the    cout << dice1 .....4

Comment: Sorry, try it now. Now it will show what you got and say if you won or not.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have at the top ‘Using namespace std`
You don’t have to specify using std::cout or anything like that.

Also you can just assign upperrange to 6 right away.

Besides this jut put it in a loop if you want, add some more output so they know they can keep playing.